# Can we import SQL bacpac file in existing DB

Tags: azure-sql-database

How to import SQL bacpac file in existing DB.

Because i can import with new DB.

But not able to import in the existing one.

Comment: Does your existing DB have data?

Comment: Hi, if my answer helped you, could you please accept it? Thanks and hava a good day.

Comment: You can overwrite existing DB! See: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/255447/94130

Comment: Luckyly, someone answered this here https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/174715/how-to-import-a-bacpac-file-to-azure-sql-and-overwrite-existing-database
Still looking into it ...

Answer (score 12):

As far as I know, Azure SQL Database doesn't support import a BACPAC file into a existing database. 
No matter in Azure SQL Database or SQL Server, they all mentioned new database.

You can reference this document:

1. Azure SQL Database: [Import BACPAC into a new database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-import).
2. SQL Server: [Import a BACPAC File to Create a New User Database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/data-tier-applications/import-a-bacpac-file-to-create-a-new-user-database?view=sql-server-2017#using-the-import-data-tier-application-wizard).

But there are many methods you can copy all data from your resource database to the existing Azure SQL database.

One of them is export all your database table view to Azure blob and import these files to your existing Azure SQL database with SSMS. I did this successfully.
You can follow my step.

**Export Data to  Blob Stroage**:
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

**Import Data from Blob Stroage** :

Using Import Data. It's  operation just the opposite of Export Data.

It has the advantage that I can import these data to my existing Azure SQL database no matter it already has data or not.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Also conveniant way is to use DataImport Wizard, but use import from local Sever to Azure servet diractly. Without blob storage as mediator.
Just select needed tables and set spec settings, if need. (insert identity and so on)
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is not impossible, it can be accomplished directly with C# code:

```
byte[] bacpac = File.ReadAllBytes(@"<local_bacpac_filepath>");

// restore what we have on production
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(bacpac))
{
    BacPackage package = BacPackage.Load(ms);

    DacServices services = new DacServices("<connection_string>");
    services.ImportBacpac(package, "<existing_database_name>");
}
```